# problem in boolean expression with if statement

Tags: c, expression

I need some confirmation. I always get  correct o/p but someone told me following expression will not work

Thanks in advance.

```
#define a 11

#define b 12

#define c 13     
    // I want if array[i] has values of any of these  then do something
    if( array[i] ==  (a) ||(b) ||( c))    
   // some function    
  else    
  printf("no match");
```

Comment: how would operator precedence play here?

Comment: Wouldn't the conditional always evaluate to true here?  `array[i] == (a)` become a _don't care_ because `(b=12) != 0` which would yield true (same for `(c)` but the `b` condition would short-circuit)?  It's been awhile since my C days...

Comment: @ Everyone... Thanks you all for helping me and clearing my doubts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

`if( array[i] == a || array[i] == b || array[i] == c)`

Each part of the boolean condition must be a complete expression. While what you wrote is valid C code, it doesn't achieve what you want: you need to make an array element comparison in every part.

Comment: Thanks  for the explanation. I will try and let you guys know

Comment: --> Thanks for quick and efficient reply.

Answer (score 2):

```
 if (array[i] ==  a || array[i] == b || array[i] == c){
       ... 
   }
```

I do wish sometimes that you could say `if (array[i] == [a, b, c])` or something to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is or'in the result of the boolean evaluation `array[i]==a` *directly* towards `b`, `c`.

In other words, `( (array[i] == a) || (b) || (c) )` is effectively what you're doing - probably not what you intended!

You will need to evaluate the boolean expressions separately:

`(array[i] == a) || (array[i] == b) ...`

Comment: To confirm my comment on the question:  Since b != 0, the conditional would always be true -- correct?

Comment: Yep, looks to me like that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

"Someone" is correct.  You need to use:

```
if ((array[i] == a) || (array[i] == b) || (array[i] == c))
```

Your program does *not* always produce correct output.  Try it with any `i` not equal to 11, 12, or 13.